# mySQL query, AND not taken into account

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a search function in PHP/MySQL. The code works fine except one issue: The AND statement doesn't work at all. I'm using the same on another page of the site where I only display the same things, and there it works perfectly. How do I get the AND statement to work when I use it in a search?

The query is following:

```
"SELECT l.Id, l.ImageId, l.Subject, l.Level, l.Aim, i.NameImg, i.AltImg 
FROM LessonPlans l 
JOIN Images i 
ON i.ImageId=l.ImageId 
WHERE lower(Subject) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lower(Level) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lower(Aim) LIKE '%".$search."%' 
AND l.Language='English' 
ORDER BY l.Id DESC;"
```

So the problem here is that `l.Language='English'` isn't taken into account at all. When searching I also get result that should only appear if `l.Language='Deutsch'` or `l.Language='French'`. Can't you use AND in a search query?

Comment: replace where condition to this: `WHERE (lower(Subject) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lower(Level) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lower(Aim) LIKE '%".$search."%' )
AND l.Language='English' ` add parenthesis

Comment: If you combine AND and OR clauses in a query, you have to use braces to avoid "misinterpretation".... there's a big difference between "Likes whisky and pizza or golf" if you don't.... "Likes (whisky and pizza) or golf" or "Likes whisky and (pizza or golf)"

Comment: Very true. The brackets fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;)

```
SELECT l.Id, l.ImageId, l.Subject, l.Level, l.Aim, i.NameImg, i.AltImg 
FROM LessonPlans l 
JOIN Images i 
ON i.ImageId=l.ImageId 
WHERE (lower(Subject) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lower(Level) LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lower(Aim) LIKE '%".$search."%') 
AND l.Language='English' 
ORDER BY l.Id DESC;
```

If you don't add `()` in `where` clause, it means when `lower(Subject) LIKE '%".$search."%'`, `lower(Level) LIKE '%".$search."%'`, `lower(Aim) LIKE '%".$search."%'`, any of these there conditions matched, next condition will not be computed.